# I installed Ubuntu onto an external usb drive, can it be used on multiple computers?

Tags: live-usb, usb-drive, external-hdd

I installed the 12.04 iso with unetbootin to a flash drive then booted into the liveusb and installed onto an external hard disks. works flawlessly so far.

My question is; Am I able to boot to it from any other computer and use as usual without problems? Or will there be missing drivers and/or any other problems?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is Yes.  Once you install Ubuntu on the external USB drive, it will be like running it from an internal drive, ***providing you don't install any proprietary drivers***.  And since its has a USB connection, you can use it on any computer that can boot from USB. Also keep in mind that it might be a little slow.

Answer (score 1):

But you may experience problems while installing drivers. It will work best until and unless you don't install drivers. Like consider you installed ATI Radeon graphic drivers for your laptop and then you plugged your external hdd on a pc with Nvidia graphics card. Obviously it's likely to create unstability as the drivers are not compatible.